# How do i solve" missing 1 required positional argument "

Tags: python, methods, typeerror

I wrote a method in class and got the following error

```
yearLinks = link(root_url + '/oilmarketreport/reports/')
TypeError: link() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'
```

My code is:-

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        try: ------
             ----
        else:

 def link(self, url):

        all_links = []
        page = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
        for href in soup.find_all(class_='omrlist'):
            all_links.append(root_url + href.find('a').get('href'))
        return all_links
 yearLinks = link(root_url + '/oilmarketreport/reports/')
 reportLinks = []
 for url in yearLinks:
     links = link(url)
```

So how i solve this in python.

Comment: What is `links`?

Comment: You needs to use `self.links(url)` or `self.link(url)` depending on what named your method.

Comment: the indentation is not clear.

Comment: links is variable having all links which we need

Comment: @ Red Cricket, links is variable name and link is method name

Comment: Error is comming in "  yearLinks = links(root_url + '/oilmarketreport/reports/') " this line

Comment: Why does `links` have a `self` argument?

Answer (score 1):

you have to do `self.link(url)`. Its missing the self parameter. 
Edit:

you can update the line as:

`yearLinks = self.link(root_url + '/oilmarketreport/reports/')`

Comment: No sir. error is comming in the yearLinks veriable. yearlinks veriable is not in any method

Comment: Sir prob is not solve yet please guide. need to integrate my code to other code So..

Comment: I think the indentation of the code in your question doesn't match your real code. Until you fix that, we won't be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

it's an unclear question. maybe staticmethod is what you wanted.

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        try: ------
             ----
        else:
 @staticmethod
 def link(url):

        all_links = []
        page = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
        for href in soup.find_all(class_='omrlist'):
            all_links.append(root_url + href.find('a').get('href'))
        return all_links
 yearLinks = Data.link(root_url + '/oilmarketreport/reports/')
 reportLinks = []
 for url in yearLinks:
     links = Data.link(url)
```

Comment: yearLinks = Data.link(root_url + '/oilmarketreport/reports/')
NameError: name 'Data' is not defined

Comment: I need to integrate my to to other code So need to put all code in class and method format. during that got above error

Comment: @royal can you check the indention? that's weird. you put code in a class.

Answer (score 0):

Just for clearness:

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self):
       """"""

    @staticmethod
    def link(url):
        return url


print(Data.link("some_link"))    # call method of class Data (will print "some_link")
```